# HTML <a> tag creates an invisible buttuon elsewhere

Tags: html, css

I was working on a dummy practice site and I tried using an anchor tag with an image so that I could have hyperlink from that image but whenever I try to change the position of the image using its position property(Relative). It just creates a invisible link of same size elsewhere on the screen. I tried multiple things but it keeps happening. Unless I move it using `position: absolute` . Help. Thanks in advance. ;)

[and I know it creates an invisible hyperlink of same size because of the pesticide extension which allows me to see all the elements on the screen.]

I guess the problem occurs when I try to move the image to a different location but I don't know why it is happening.[ And please ignore my inefficient code, started Web development couple of days ago ;)]

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #222831;
}

nav{
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}

nav .icon{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0 0px 10px;
    color: #121212;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

.search-bar{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 7px;
    left: 10px;
    background: url(../Images/search-icon.png) no-repeat scroll 2px 2px;
    padding-left:30px;
    width: 400px;
}

nav h1{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
}

.profile-pic{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #121212;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/home.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="../Images/menu.png">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
        <nav>
            <img src="../Images/menu.png" alt="SQUARE LOGO" class = "icon">
            <input type="text" class="search-bar" id="search-bar">
            <h1>SQUARE</h1>
        </nav>
        
 <a href="index.html"><img  class="profile-pic" src="../Images/user.png" alt="Profile Picture"  href="index.html "></a>  <!-- This is the code producing error--!>
 
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML tags always need a closing hint. For example, `<a>` needs the "counterpart" `</a>`. In your `<img>` and `<input> `tags you don't have a closing counterpart, and that's acceptable, because you can hit a closing tag within the same tag like so: `<input type="text" class="search-bar" id="search-bar" />`. Note the `/>` at the end. That means that there's not going to be a closing counterpart for this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use relative as the absolute positioning will default relative to the body.  You do need to add left or top to the absolute element

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #222831;
}

nav{
    background-color: #ebebeb;
   
    padding: 5px;
}

nav .icon{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0 0px 10px;
    color: #121212;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

.search-bar{
   
    bottom: 7px;
    left: 10px;
    background: url(../Images/search-icon.png) no-repeat scroll 2px 2px;
    padding-left:30px;
    width: 400px;
}

nav h1{
    display: inline-block;
   
    
}

.profile-pic{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #121212;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    right: 200px;
    left:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/home.css">
    <img  src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
        <nav>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="SQUARE LOGO" class = "icon">
            <input type="text" class="search-bar" id="search-bar">
            <h1>SQUARE</h1>
        </nav>
        
 <a href="index.html"><img  class="profile-pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="Profile Picture"  > </a>  
 
    
</body>
</html>
```